# Range matching in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a range matching application in Python. These are my inputs:

```py
rx_initial = 100
rx_final = 200
tx_initial = 50
tx_final = 150
```

The output should be "**the ranges that matches from `100` to `150`**".

I want an application that matches different ranges of integers. I've made lists for the inputs, then I've made a for loop with conditionals. Everything works fine if I only have 1 `tx` to be compared with any number of `rx`.

Now I'm trying to find a way to make it work with more than 1 `tx`.
Any ideas of how do I compare the index 0 of a `tx_list` with an entire `rx_list`, and when it's done, then it begins comparing the index 1 of the `tx_list` with the entire `rx_list` again, until all elements from the `tx_list` are compared with all elements from the `rx_list`?

I'm totally new to python and StackOverflow. Thank you very much for your help.

My Code example:

```py
rx_inicial = [100, 150, 200]
rx_final = [200, 250, 300]
tx_inicial = [50]
tx_final = [150]

numero_rx = 3
numero_tx = 1
numero_vueltas = numero_rx * numero_tx

contador = 0
contador_rx = 0
contador_tx = 0

def EmpAntesTermEntre():
    return(int(tx_final[contador_tx]) - int(rx_inicial[contador_rx]))

def EmpEntreTermEntre():
    return(int(tx_final[contador_tx]) - int(tx_inicial[contador_tx]))

def EmpEntreTermDespues():
    return(int(rx_final[contador_rx]) - int(tx_inicial[contador_tx]))

def EmpAntesTermDespues():
    return(int(rx_final[contador_rx]) - int(rx_inicial[contador_rx]))


for _ in range(0, numero_vueltas):
    if tx_inicial[contador_tx] < rx_inicial[contador_rx] and tx_final[contador_tx] > rx_inicial[contador_rx] and tx_final[contador_tx] <= rx_final[contador_rx]:
        print(f"El sistema {contador + 1} coincide en {EmpAntesTermEntre()} MHz.")
    elif tx_inicial[contador_tx] < rx_inicial[contador_rx] and tx_final[contador_tx] == rx_inicial[contador_rx]:
        print(f"El sistema {contador + 1} coincide APENAS en la frecuencia de {int(tx_final[contador])} MHz.")
    elif tx_inicial[contador_tx] >= rx_inicial[contador_rx] and tx_final[contador_tx] <= rx_final[contador_rx]:
        print(f"El sistema {contador + 1} coincide en {EmpEntreTermEntre()} MHz.")
    elif tx_inicial[contador_tx] >= rx_inicial[contador_rx] and tx_inicial[contador_tx] < rx_final[contador_rx] and tx_final[contador_tx] > rx_final[contador_rx]:
        print(f"El sistema {contador + 1} coincide en {EmpEntreTermDespues()} MHz.")
    elif tx_final[contador_tx] > rx_final[contador_rx] and tx_inicial[contador_tx] == rx_final[contador_rx]:
        print(f"El sistema {contador + 1} coincide APENAS en la frecuencia de {int(tx_inicial[contador_tx])} MHz.")
    elif tx_inicial[contador_tx] <= rx_inicial[contador_rx] and tx_final[contador_tx] >= rx_final[contador_rx]:
        print(f"El sistema {contador + 1} coincide en {EmpAntesTermDespues()} MHz.")
    else:
        print(f"Los rangos del sistema {contador + 1} no cuadran.")
    contador += 1
```

Comment: Welcome.  Can you please update the question with what you’ve tried so far and where you’ve gotten stuck?  This will help us help you better.

Comment: As you can see in my code, it works fine to compare 1 item list of tx with x items list of rx. But I need it to compare all items from the tx lists with all items from the rx lists. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a small change to your code.

Here it is:

```
rx_inicial = [100, 150, 200]
rx_final = [200, 250, 300]
tx_inicial = [50, 70, 100]
tx_final = [150, 200, 250]

numero_rx = 3
numero_tx = 3

contador = 0

def EmpAntesTermEntre(tx, rx):
    return(int(tx_final[tx]) - int(rx_inicial[rx]))

def EmpEntreTermEntre(tx):
    return(int(tx_final[tx]) - int(tx_inicial[tx]))

def EmpEntreTermDespues(tx, rx):
    return(int(rx_final[rx]) - int(tx_inicial[tx]))

def EmpAntesTermDespues(rx):
    return(int(rx_final[rx]) - int(rx_inicial[rx]))

for tx in range(numero_tx):
    for rx in range(numero_rx):
        if tx_inicial[tx] < rx_inicial[rx] and tx_final[tx] > rx_inicial[rx] and tx_final[tx] <= rx_final[rx]:
            print(f"El sistema {contador + 1} coincide en {EmpAntesTermEntre(tx, rx)} MHz.")

        elif tx_inicial[tx] < rx_inicial[rx] and tx_final[tx] == rx_inicial[rx]:
            print(f"El sistema {contador + 1} coincide APENAS en la frecuencia de {int(tx_final[tx])} MHz.")

        elif tx_inicial[tx] >= rx_inicial[rx] and tx_final[tx] <= rx_final[rx]:
            print(f"El sistema {contador + 1} coincide en {EmpEntreTermEntre(tx, rx)} MHz.")

        elif tx_inicial[tx] >= rx_inicial[rx] and tx_inicial[tx] < rx_final[rx] and tx_final[tx] > rx_final[rx]:
            print(f"El sistema {contador + 1} coincide en {EmpEntreTermDespues(tx, rx)} MHz.")

        elif tx_final[tx] > rx_final[rx] and tx_inicial[tx] == rx_final[rx]:
            print(f"El sistema {contador + 1} coincide APENAS en la frecuencia de {int(tx_inicial[tx])} MHz.")

        elif tx_inicial[tx] <= rx_inicial[rx] and tx_final[tx] >= rx_final[rx]:
            print(f"El sistema {contador + 1} coincide en {EmpAntesTermDespues(rx)} MHz.")
        else:
            print(f"Los rangos del sistema {contador + 1} no cuadran.")
        contador += 1
```

What I changed:
I made the main "for loop" loop through each tx and through each rx for every tx, this way you compare every tx with every rx.

I hope this solves your problem, however your code is a little bit messy and could use some improvements. I'll try to clean it a little and afterwards edit this answer.

Edited Answer:

I managed to shorten it a bit:

```
rx_inicial = [100, 150, 200]
rx_final = [200, 250, 300]
tx_inicial = [50, 70, 100]
tx_final = [150, 200, 250]

contador = 0
for (txInicial, txFinal) in zip(tx_inicial, tx_final):
    for (rxInicial, rxFinal) in zip(rx_inicial, rx_final):
        #Find the inicial value
        if txInicial > rxInicial : inicial = txInicial
        else : inicial = rxInicial

        #Find the final value
        if txFinal < rxFinal : final = txFinal
        else : final = rxFinal

        if inicial == final:
            print(f"El sistema {contador + 1} coincide APENAS en la frecuencia de {int(inicial)} MHz.")
        elif inicial < final:
            print(f"El sistema {contador + 1} coincide en {int(final - inicial)} MHz.")
        else:
            print(f"Los rangos del sistema {contador + 1} no cuadran.")
        contador += 1
```

It's also more readable. What it does is it also loops through each tx value and then each rx value for each tx. However it iterates through the list using zip, [about the zip() function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-iterate-multiple-lists-simultaneously/), instead of getting the index of each.

I simplified the conditions, now it first calculates the final and inicial limits and then checks were the ranges "coincide".

Hopefully I was of any help